# This program loops the same thing over and over again and I want it to do it once and continuing on to the other programs below the loop

Tags: python, while-loop

When I run this, it just keeps on repeating itself asking for a number over and over again. I am a beginner at python so please don't judge.

```
import random
import time

while True:
    guess = input("Please enter a lucky number between 1 to 10:\n")
    number = random.randint(0, 10)
    print ("Random number is " + str(number) + ":")
    if guess == number:
        print ("Awesome - You guessed correctly!")
        answer = input('Would you like to try again? (y/n):\n')
        def func():
            if answer == 'n':
                print ("Have a wonderful day!")
                time.sleep(2)
else:
    print("Good try, Would you like to play again? (y/n):")     
    func()
```

Comment: `guess == number` will never be true. `guess` is a string, `number` is a number. You need to convert one of them to the other type.

Comment: The `else:` block will never be executed. It's only exited if the loop exits because the `while` condition fails. But `while True:` can never fail.

Comment: What's the reason for the `func()` function? Just do the `if` normally, it doesn't need to be in a function.

Comment: And if they say no, use `break` to end the loop.

Comment: Oh yeah your right, I'm like really knew to coding. Thanks a lot though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```py
import random
import time

number = random.randint(0, 10)

while True:
    guess = int(input("Please enter a lucky number between 1 to 10:\n"))
    
    print ("Random number is " + str(number) + ":")
    if guess == number:
        print ("Awesome - You guessed correctly!")
        answer = input('Would you like to try again? (y/n):\n')
        if answer == 'n':
            print ("Have a wonderful day!")
            break
        else:
            print("generating new number...")
            number = random.randint(0, 10)
```